# Como criar uma lista (no python) que todos os elementos presentes tenham um número x específico?

Tags: python-3.x

Boa noite, eu sou um iniciante extremo em python e eu tenho a dúvida de:
como que dá para fazer uma lista, de por exemplo 3000 a 6000 em que apenas elementos que o segundo número seja, por exemplo 2, (tipo 1230) apareçam na lista?
Eu acho que eu tenho que colocar "If", mas eu não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer esse requisito.
Aqui em baixo tá o esboço do que eu tentei fazer:

a=[]
for g in range(3000,6001):
if(g(1)==2):
a.append(str(g))

print("/ /".join(a))

Da erro dizendo que int não pode ser chamado, e outra dúvida relacionada a esse código, pq eu tenho que colocar "str"?
Esse código é de um exercício, e quando eu mudei o str para int dava erro dizendo "expected str instante"
Pq isso ocorre? Pq tem que ser sting e não int? Pq é esperado str?
Eu n sei se pode fazer duas perguntas no mesmo post, sinto muito qualquer coisa, obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Vc vai precisar pegar vários ranges: de 3200 a 3299, de 4200 a 4299 e de 5200 a 5299.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

boa noite!

Tenho uma solução, pode não ser a melhor ok.
Num intervalo de 250 a 300 vou pegar números que o 2.º índice seja 2 ou 5.
E adicionar na lista "escolhidos" apenas para ver o resultado

Basta transformar o i em string e fazer o que quiser com ele, até transformar em int novamente se quiser, para fazer operações aritméticas

```
escolhidos = []

for i in range(250, 301):
    i = str(i)
    if i[1] in ["2", "5"]:
        escolhidos.append(i)
        
print(escolhidos)
```

Resultado:

```
['250', '251', '252', '253', '254', '255', '256', '257', '258', '259']
```

Testa ai e me diz se funcionou :)

Comment: Sim, funcionou perfeitamente, consegui fazer o que queria. Obrigado! Mas uma dúvida, se usa a função str() pq dá para modificar como quiser? (Sinto muito, mas n posso dar voto positivo pq n tenho pontos suficientes)

Comment: Eu digo no sentido de fazer tudo o que você quiser com o número, fatiar, pegar o índice, como eu fiz para te ajudar... fazer tudo que você faz com uma string mesmo, pois é uma string. E quanto ao voto positivo, sem problemas ok :)

Comment: Obrigado pela informação, eu tava em dúvida nos str. Valeu 